# How to fix mongoose findOne returning empty when setting multidimensional array in map?

Tags: mongoose, promise

How to fix mongoose findOne returning empty when setting multidimensional array in map?

I've already tried to utilize a callback function, and I've heard about promises. I tried implementing the two but I'm having a difficult time. When I output console of user it gives me the user object, however after returning model.reviews it isn't defined.

```
  if(!_.isEmpty(model.reviews)){

    let result = model.reviews.map(async (item, index)=>{
      console.log('item', item)
      console.log('model', model)

      let user = await User.findOne({ _id: item.user_id }).lean().exec((error, model)=>{ if (error || !model) { return error } else { return model } })
      console.log('user', user)

      model.reviews[index].user = user
    })
  }

  return res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', response: 200, message: 'Found single model.', data: model });
}
```

I expect to get model.reviews[index].user = USER, but model.reviews[index].user isn't defined in the returned model.reviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    let result = await Promise.all(model.reviews.map(async (item, index)=>{
      console.log('item', item)
      console.log('model', model)

      let user = await User.findOne({ _id: item.user_id }, function (error, user){
        if (error || !user) { return error }
        else {
          return user
        }
      })

      model.reviews[index].user = user


    }))
```